# How can I change the developer name in Huawei AppGallery?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery, appgallery-connect

I registered alone using my real name just to upload the app, but I'd like the developer name be accredited to the team I belong to..

Answer (score 4):

To change the developer name, please execute the following steps.
After logging into your Huawei developer account,  go to Developer center->Settings-> My profile and then change the developer name there.
[image]

Comment: I did this but only the developer name has changed & provider name still showing my real name. Any idea about why it's happening?